# Carousel picture size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to ask what's the correct picture size on a carousel on `Bootstrap`? I'm a beginner using `Bootstrap`, so I would like to know the correct size of the picture or any idea/tips you guys recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really not a topic to worry about .

The size of image get decreases with screen size since width: 100% does ur job in bootstrap.

But thing you should worry about is that all the image should have same aspect ratio .

The aspect ratio is upon the how much you want your carousel to cover your screen .

For me , When i want small carousel to my page below menu bar and carousel after that i prefer 1200x700 for carousel image .

It depend on ur design need .